# AIDE dropped Dropbox Integration

Tags: dropbox, aide-ide

Some time ago, I was able to sync my desktop Android development with my mobile development using AIDE through Dropbox.  However, I am now told that AIDE does not support the new version of Dropbox and the old version was retired on September 28, 2017.

Is AIDE ever going to acknowledge the change, or do I need to find a new mobile development solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not acknowledging the change.  They removed the Dropbox option.  Looks like they are using github for their cloud storage now.

Answer (score 0):

This allowed you to sync your Dropbox with your AIDE folder:

Folder Sync is an android app that sync btw your cloud storage (Dropbox, Google Drive, One Drive, etc) and your android device. This worked for me!

For more info of the app, here is the link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite

Comment: This allowed you to sync your Dropbox with AIDE?